# How to include large numbers in transactions >=1e21

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I am testing an ERC20 Token on the Rinkeby testnet.

I am sending `transfer` transactions of 1e23 units.
The response from web3 says

I have tried converting the amount to a string using the Javascript toString method.
And converting with `web3.utils.toHex()`.

Both return errors

```
dat=token.methods.transfer(w3.utils.toHex(to),web3.utils.toHex(amount)).encodeABI()

/*
OR 
dat=token.methods.transfer(w3.utils.toHex(to),web3.utils.toHex(amount)).encodeABI()

*/

w3.eth.sendTransaction({from:from,to:TOKEN_ADDRESS,data:dat,gas:gasLimit()},(err,txhash)=>{
        if(err) throw err
        console.log(txhash)
        callback(txhash)    
    })

Uncaught Error: Please pass numbers as strings or BigNumber objects to avoid precision errors.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TLDR

Use the built-in util functions to convert ether to wei:

```
var amount = web3.utils.toWei('1000000','ether');
```

---

### Old answer below:

Literally just follow the advise of the error.

The `to` number should initially be of type string because the number type in javascript is too small to store addresses.

If the `amount` starts of as a reasonable number then convert it to BigNumber using a bignumber library. Web3 internally uses [bn.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bn.js) as its bignumber library so for full compatibility you should also use the same but [bignum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignum) is also compatible in my experience:

```
const BN = require('bn.js');

token.methods.transfer(new BN(to),new BN(amount)).encodeABI()
```

---

Based on your comment it appears you are trying to pass `1e+24` as a number. The problem is it is too large to fit in a double without losing precision. Web3 is refusing to use the number because it has already lost precision even before web3 has a chance to process it. The fix is to use a string instead:

```
var amount = '1000000000000000000000000';
token.methods.transfer(to,amount).encodeABI()
```

If you **really** don't want to type 24 zeros you can use string operations:

```
var amount = '1' + '0'.repeat(24);
```

Or if this is amount is really a million ethers it's better to use the built-in util functions to show what you really mean:

```
var amount = web3.utils.toWei('1000000','ether');
```

Comment: I tried that on 1e+24 and got 'Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed'

Comment: It doesn't recognise 1e+24. You need to do `new BN("1000000000000000000000000")`

Comment: Admittedly, if this was your problem, you may not need bn.js. You could have just used `"1000000000000000000000000"`

Comment: ^^ -- don't just copy/paste my number. Count the number of zeros and make sure it has 24 of them

Comment: you could also use web3.utils.toWei('100','ether') for big numbers to multiply the amount by 1e18

Comment: Ah, yes. You really shouldn't manually calculate wei unless you're doing microtransactions

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but i was having troubble with some tests for solidity using chai and i added this comment:

`/* global BigInt */`

With that you can use big numbers

`const testValue = 2000000000000000000n;`